# Django MySQL entry unique ID or pk

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a model form that saves a request for a change and notifies the admins via email if a new entry is created. The admin gets and mild notification with the link to go review the entry http://mydjango/admin and they log in to view and approve or deny request. The admins would like to have the link above takes them directly to the entry rather than to the admin site and having them navigate through the list of entries to find the latest one.
I have to say that I'm super new to django and would like to see if this is possible. I have noticed that if I go to an entry and click on it, the link on my browser have a unique number for an example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app/changerequests/61/change/

there is that 61 that changes for every entry. So i was thinking maybe include that "id" of the newly created entry in the email that goes out to the admin.

her is my model,form,view,admin

model.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from app.forms import SignUpForm

# Create your models here.
class ChangeRequests(models.Model):
    ENV_CHOICE = (
        ('select', 'Select'),
        ('Production', 'Production'),
        ('Lab', 'Lab'),
        ('EBC_env', 'EBC_env'),
        ('Los_Angles', 'Los Angles'),
        )
    request_status = (
        ('select', 'Select'),
        ('Pending...', 'Pending...'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Denied', 'Denied'),
        ('Added_comment', 'Added_comment'),
        )
    email = models.EmailField()

    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    what_is_the_change = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)
    impact = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True, help_text="Provide an example of the impact this change might cause")
    environment = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ENV_CHOICE, default='select')
    change_date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date/time of change. Use format: 3/30/2016 20:30")#, help_text="time example: <em>03/30/2016 20:30</em>")
    #test_time = models.CharField(widget=SelectDateWidget, initial=datetime.date.today())
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=request_status, default='Pending...', blank=True)
    status_reason = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)


    #this code is for checking the status of the request and sends an email with a message based on the comment left by the admins:
    __original_status = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChangeRequests, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_status = self.status


    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.status != self.__original_status:
            subject = "Request for a change status changed"
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER + "@company.com"
            if  self.status_reason != "":
                contact_message = """
            Hi: %s
            Your request to make a change to: %s
            Has been: (%s)
            wiht the following comment: (%s)
            """%(self.full_name, self.environment, self.status, self.status_reason)
            else:
                contact_message = """
                ---------
                - Hi: %s
                - 
                Your request to make a change to: %s
                Has been: (%s)
                """%(self.full_name, self.environment, self.status)
            to_email = (self.email,)
            send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=False)





        super(ChangeRequests, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_status = self.status




    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from app.models import ChangeRequests
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime





class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ChangeRequests
        fields = ('full_name', 'email', 'environment', 'what_is_the_change', 'change_date_and_time','impact')


    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        return email

    def clean_full_name(self):
        full_name = self.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
        return full_name
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from app.forms import SignUpForm, ContactForm
from app.models import ChangeRequests
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse


# Create your views here.

@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    title = "WELCOME GUEST"


    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form
    }

    if form.is_valid():#this cases the form to be saved into the DB I can also have it where if form.is_valid(): form.save()
        form.save()
        form_email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        form_message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        form_full_name = form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
        form_environment = form.cleaned_data.get("environment")
        form_what_is_the_change = form.cleaned_data.get("what_is_the_change")
        form_change_date_and_time = form.cleaned_data.get("change_date_and_time")
        #form_status = form.cleaned_data.get("status")
        subject = "Request for a change"
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER + "@company.com"
        to_email = ["test@company.com"]
        contact_message = """
User: %s

Email: %s

Requesting the following change: (%s)

Environment affected: (%s)

Date and time of the change: %s
Admin approvals and review >>>>> http://myserver/admin and use your admin login credentials.
        """%(form_full_name, form_email, form_what_is_the_change, form_environment, form_change_date_and_time)

        send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/submitted')

        context = {
            "title": "Thank you"
        }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see where you're including any kind of link in that email, but you can certainly use the [reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) functionality to create a link direct to your content.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

...

if form.is_valid():
    item = form.save()
    link = reverse('admin:app_changerequests_change', args=(item.id,))
    url = "https://ADDRESS_OF_MY_SITE{}".format(link)
```

and you can include that `url` value in your email.

Comment: thanks @Daniel I get the error below when I put your code in my view.py  `local variable 'item' referenced before assignment`

Comment: You wouldn't get that with my code. Perhaps you have an indentation issue?

Answer (score 0):

As like your model for that, it is same. So, you can pass id or pk.

For your knowledge, Django is always add `id` field in each model for uniqueness, and `pk` means your primary key field. so, you can assign any field to primary key(by default it assigned to `id` field). so, you have once assigned primary key is true for any one field. then, when you call `pk`. It will return primary key field's value.

Hopefully, it will help for you. :)

Comment: thanks @Naresh Chaudhary I have tried this but it kept on saying form have no attribute "id"...... I must've been doing it wrong. Would you tell me -in the context of my code above- where and how to use the id or pk?

Comment: I think @Daniel Roseman code, you used. if not than tell me I will write for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the right admin change url for model object using

```
reverse('admin:app_model_change', args=(model_object.id))
```

Send the url in your email.